# Center text horizontally and vertically in a circle

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where the text isn't appearing in the center of the circle, how can I fix that please?

```css
#indexClient {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #99CCCC
}
```

```html
<div id="indexClient">
  <p>Client Side</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### **Approach 1: `line-height` equal `height` tricks**

(works for single line of text).

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #9cc;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Hello</div>
```

#### **Approach 2: `line-height` + `inline-block`**

(works for both single and multiple lines of text).

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #9cc;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>Test Long Item</span>
</div>
```

#### **Approach 3: using CSS `table` + `table-cell`**

(works for both single and multiple lines of text).

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #9cc;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.circle span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>Test Long Item</span>
</div>
```

#### **Approach 4: using CSS3 [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)**

(works for both single and multiple lines of text).

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #9cc;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>Test Long Item</span>
</div>
```